Question regarding the balance sheet
I am aware of the fact the assets = liabilities + equity and how this represents how the assets were financed
However I have a question regarding this , the first being how is it that the actual value of the assets of the company can be equal to its liabilities and equity , since things like loans increase with time due to interest and equity can decrease with time due to stock price . So say this company is not making enough revenues such that it can't keep up with even the interest payments ergo their liabilities are only getting larger and for the sake of argument we can assume the stock price is also very low .
How is it that then the value of their assets is decreasing? Say machinery, for example, the value of the machinery is unrelated to the change in the company's liabilities and its stock price. I say this because when liabilities increase how can we assume that it's because the company is taking on more debt to finance more assets, could it not just be that liabilities are increasing due to interest or the loans weren't even being used to finance assets etc?

Equity doesn't decrease with stock price, the market value does. Equity = assets - liabilities.

Equity has two different meanings.  Here, thanks to the magic of double-entry bookkeeping, the balance statement of equity is assets minus liabilities, in effect subscribed capital plus accumulated net profits (sometimes called reserves). If the shares in the company are traded, the share price is what matches people wanting to buy and sell the shares, and often is not based on the book-value of equity as stated in the balance sheet.


I say this because when liabilities increase how can we assume that it's because the company is taking on more debt to finance more assets, could it not just be that liabilities are increasing due to interest or the loans weren't even being used to finance assets etc?

You misunderstand how corporate long-term liabilities work. Corporations can't just choose not to pay their bond interest, otherwise they would be in default and likely have to declare bankruptcy.
So liabilities going up is not from interest accruing - it would be because they are not paying off their short-term debts (which would easily be seen by comparing current debt from one period to another) or by borrowing more long-term debt.
Second, "equity" in the balance sheet has very little to do with stock price. It is simply the net difference between the assets and the liabilities. It is categorized in order to explain why that difference changes (e.g. net profits are reflected in retained earnings, and additional paid-in capital reflects the cash received from the initial sale stock above the book value), but it does not fluctuate with stock price.

how is it that the actual value of the assets of the company can be equal to its liabilities and equity

Simple examples:

if machinery is depreciated, it reduces the asset value and is booked as an expense, which reduces the equity. So debt is unchanged, the asset value is reduced, and thus equity (asset-liability_ is reduced through the expense. Everything balances.

As a company makes sales (let's say for cash to keep it simple), its assets (cash) increase, liabilities are unchanged, and equity is increased through the net profit. Everything balances.



D Stanley's answer is great there is only one thing I would add. Equity is a liability to the investors so it's a long, long, long term liability.

This was actually very insightful, one doubt I do have though is if we are taking on more liabilities, how can we be so sure that it is used to finance assets therefore how can we be sure that asset value goes up?

I'm not sure what you mean - you can compare assets from one period to another and see if they go up. Remember though that the book value of assets is based on their cost, not necessarily market value (with some exceptions for asset write-downs), So if assets go up it means that new assets were purchased, which could have been with cash, debt, or equity. One would have to do a deeper analysis of the company overall to determine how things were financed.

What I mean is say we borrow more money therefore our liabilities go up , according to the equation our assets should also increase ,but this is assuming that the money we borrow is to purchase more assets .But this doesn't always have to be the case ie not every time a company borrows money doesn't mean they did it to finance assets ,so how can we be sure assets increase when liabilities go up since the debt increase doesn't mean they are necessarily using it to finance assets.

What I mean is say we borrow more money therefore our liabilities go up , according to the equation our assets should also increase ,but this is assuming that the money we borrow is to purchase more assets .But this doesn't always have to be the case ie not every time a company borrows money doesn't mean they did it to finance assets ,so how can we be sure assets increase when liabilities go up since the debt increase doesn't mean they are necessarily using it to finance assets. Unless you view the cash gained from the loan as an asset in itself

Cash is most definitely an asset. If you borrow money, cash goes up and liabilities go up. That cash then could be used to buy assets, which is a net zero effect on assets. Borrowing money has zero effect on equity.
